# First Try at Using jQuery: Stuck on get() Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a dropdown suggestion box using jQuery. I have a function that looks like this:

```
function onChoiceSelected(index){
    var item = $("#suggestionBox li").get(index);
    alert("inner html: "+item.html());
    currentSuggestionInput.val(item.html());
    hideSuggestions();
}
```

For some reason, that get function is stopping execution. If I replace it with `.first()`, for example, it all works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

**Follow up question:**

- Is there some way to see what errors are happening, rather than just having silent failure?
- I'm running firebug, but I never see any errors or anything like that. Anyone know a good article about getting a proper development environment set up for this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` method returns the DOM node at the index specified. Since you are then trying to call a jQuery method on that, it will fail.

The `eq` method should do what you want. It will have the same effect as your `get` call, but it will return a jQuery object rather than the DOM node itself.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), not [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
var item = $("#suggestionBox li").eq(index);
```

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is DOM node
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is the jQuery object.

Comment: I think that the issue is about using this version of get - http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: @BrianHoover you caught me before I linked to the correct version, I grabbed the first result from Google not paying attention to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing errors in the console of firebug.

You can also use tools like console.log(index) in firebug, as well as run the javascript directly from the console screen.

What value are you getting for index?

Answer (score 0):

do it as

```
function onChoiceSelected(index){
    var item = $($("#suggestionBox li").get(index));
    alert("inner html: "+item.html());
    currentSuggestionInput.val(item.html());
    hideSuggestions();
}
```